# Some files in CIFS directory cannot be overwrite once created/copied

Tags: centos, filenames, samba, cifs, shared-folders

I have encountered a strange behavior in one of the CIFS mount directory. For example, I copy a file to the directory, `cp /mnt/source/movie.mp4 /mnt/target/` . First time it runs successfully. But when I tried to overwrite the file with the same command, `cp /mnt/source/movie.mp4 /mnt/target/`, the system returned Permission Denied.

I suspect it is due to filename problem, apparently, if I renamed the file, I can then overwrite the file. I then rename the file back to the same name, and the problem is gone. I have checked both the original filename and new name using `file -bi movie.mp4`, and both return `video/mp4; charset=binary`. What could have wrong in the filename?

I also did another test, after I copied the file for first time, I realized the destination file permission became 555. I changed it to 777, then went back to the source folder and do the `cp` again, it then allowed me to overwrite it. But if I renamed the file first (or create my own new file), the copied destination file permission is 777, same I will get 777 for any new file created in the destination folder. Why would the source file's filename affect the file permission in the destination folder?

**Some Information about the Environment**

The folder permission of the target folder is `drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 0 Apr 12 23:44 20180427031647`.
I'm using `root` user to perform the `cp` command.

- Kernel version: 3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64
- CentOS version: 7.7.1908 (Core)
- cifs-utils-6.2-10.el7.x86_64

fstab mount parameter:

`vers=2.0,credentials=/root/.credentials,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,iocharset=utf8`